Is It Feasible to Compile a Kernel in the Debian Way in Linux-Mint?
I found this Debian guide on compiling a kernel: Debian: Common Kernel-related Tasks.
Is it safe to follow its instruction to compile a kernel in a Linux-mint box? Or anyone has any more reliable guides for that?

AFAIK Mint runs Ubuntu kernels. Other than that all methods applicable to Debian are also applicable to Ubuntu/Mint. The thing is you don't have to compile: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=392059 but you can if you want https://www.instructables.com/Compile-custom-linux-kernel-in-MintUbuntuLMDE/
